# PM2 receives errors when running bash script

Tags: bash, pm2

I keep receiving error when running a bash script that delete files over a certain number of days old.

[image: 1]

However, this particular process' log file doesn't contain any entries. How do I confirm what went wrong with this process?

My bash script is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

find /home/collector/cloudtrail/ -mtime +3 -exec rm {} +
find /home/collector/stackdriver/ -mtime +3 -exec rm {} +
```

I tried looking at the process' logs with `pm2 logs 8` but it doesn't show me anything.

Comment: You might want to search for a wrapper tool that reports helpful errors if bash fails. Something gdb-like maybe but more syntactically intuitive for the purpose if such a tool exists. Or maybe write a script where you can intuitively utilize gdb, which wouldn't be easy of course. It may also not work.

Comment: @Zack me too, got the reasons why?